# Alternatives to JavaScript eval() for parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, json, eval

Quick Question. Eval in JavaScript is unsafe is it not? I have a JSON object as a string and I need to turn it into an actual object so I can obtain the data:

```
function PopulateSeriesFields(result) 
{
    data = eval('(' + result + ')');
    var myFakeExample = data.exampleType
}
```

If it helps I am using the $.ajax method from jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646597/eval-is-evil-so-what-should-i-use-instead

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, safe or not, when you are using jQuery, you're better to use the [$.getJSON()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) method, not $.ajax():

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    alert(data.exampleType);
});
```

`eval()` is usually considered safe for JSON parsing when you are only communicating with your own server and especially when you use a good JSON library on server side that guarantees that generated JSON will not contain anything nasty.

Even Douglas Crockford, the author of JSON, said that you shouldn't use `eval()` anywhere in your code, except for parsing JSON. See the corresponding section in his book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=JavaScript:+The+Good+Parts+eval&source=bl&ots=HHpll5r0gG&sig=3OTFEqDnRBVaLXSUDK1JsCGvxIg&hl=et&ei=4pcmSs7FAsG__Qa_2P3XBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2)

Comment: I was writing the exact same thing +1

Comment: Sure, bug getJSON() is shorter to write.

Comment: except that $.getJSON() doesn't provide nearly the flexibility that $.ajax() does. Particularly in the handling of errors, success/complete events, etc...

Answer (score 19):

You should use [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) and write JSON.parse.

"Manual" parsing is too slow, so JSON.parse implementation from the library checks stuff and then ends up using eval, so it is [still unsafe](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/10/json-and-browser-security/). But, if you are using a newer browser (IE8 or Firefox), the library code is not actually executed. Instead, **native browser support** kicks in, and then you are safe.

Read more [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/12/native-json-in-firefox-31/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/ is a manual parser that aims to be fast and secure.  You are right though that the native support should be preferred where available.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't trust the source, then you're correct...eval is unsafe. It could be used to inject code into your pages.

Check out this link for a safer alternative:

[JSON in Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

The page explains why eval is unsafe and provides a link to a JSON parser at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5):

Unsafe? That depends on if you can trust the data.

If you can trust that the string will be JSON (and won't include, for example, functions) then it is safe.

That said - if you are using jQuery, why are you doing this manually? Use the [dataType](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) option to specify that it is JSON and let the library take care of it for you.

Comment: @J-P: But only if JSON is not available. http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/ajax.js#L504

Comment: I have the dataType thing but it still comes back as a string. Hang on, i'll try application/JSON

Comment: It seems that JSON is just available as a plugin and not a build-in component of jQuery for those that doesn’t support native JSON.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery, as of version 1.4.1 you can use jQuery.parseJSON()

See this answer: [Safe json parsing with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016236/safe-json-parsing-with-jquery/3016292#3016292)

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript’s `eval` is unsafe. Because JSON is just a subset of JavaScript but JavaScript’s `eval` allows any valid JavaScript.

Use a real JSON parser like the [JSON parser from json.org](http://json.org/js.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative to evaluating the code is to parse it manually. It's not as hard as it sounds but it's quite a lot heavier at runtime. [You can read about it here.](http://www.json.org/js.html)

The important part to note is evaluating JSON is not inherently insecure. As long as you trust the source not to balls things up. That includes making sure that things passed into the JSON encoder are properly escaped (to stop people 2 steps up the stream executing code on your users' machines).

Answer (score 2):

you can try it like this

```
var object = new Function("return " + jsonString)()
```

Comment: This is simply an eval alias.

Comment: @WillMorgan: Honestly when I first saw this, my jaw dropped, as i recalled that jQuery uses the exact same lines for JSON evaluation. However on investigating, this is arguably not "eval", see ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/is-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing ' for more information. [Btw i edited the answer to reflect this piece of information, kind of unfair for 'TheBrain' to be down voted for the wrong reasons]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.  The question asked whether a particular kind of code pattern is safe or not.  You don't answer that question.  You just say "here's some other code you could use", which doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Another great alternative is YUI:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/json/

So your code would be something like:

```
Y.JSON.parse('{"id": 15, "name": "something"}');
```