# Jquery JSON response handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax query written in jQuery that is returning valid JSON in this format

```
$.ajax({
   type     : 'POST',
   url      : 'ajax/job/getActiveJobs.php',
   success  : function(data){
       if(data[''] === true){
           alert('json decoded');
       }

       $('#waiting').hide(500);
       $('#tableData').html(data['content']);
       $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true)
       ?'error':'success').text(data.msg);
       if(data.error === true)
           $('#message')

   },
   error    : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       $('#waiting').hide(500);
       $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error').html(data.msg);
   } })
```

I take it this is not correct as it is not displaying the data, if I use

```
$('#mydiv').html(data);
```

I get all of the data back and displayed.

any help is really appreciated

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd post the complete code of your ajax "success" handler. What you've posted here does not look wrong, so it must be something else.

Comment: Try an `alert(data)` and check what type of object you get. May be it's not interpreted as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set `dataType` to `json` or use `var json = JSON.parse(data)` to do it manually.

**EDIT**:

I'm adding this because somebody else suggested `eval`, don't do this because it gets passed straight into a `JSON` object without any sanitation first, allowing scripts to get passed leading straight into an `XSS` vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks Connor Smith I will be accepting your answer in precisely 6 minutes lol how weird I can't accept an answer when yours has solved the problem. I will not be using eval() dont worry :) Thanks again

Comment: No, it uses: `new Function("return " + data))();` if JSON.parse is not available. Source, jQuery source code: https://gist.github.com/277432

Comment: @Connor I deleted it after I realised you didn't use `$.parseJSON()` (I was imagining things). BTW, passing a string to `new Function()` is basically an `eval()`.

Comment: @alex It seems that it is indeed as bad security-wise but that new Function() is better, smarter, at parsing the data and is faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449220/jquery-uses-new-functionreturn-data-instead-of-evaldata-to-parse-j

Answer (score 4):

Set the `dataType` to be `json` so jQuery will convert the JSON to a JavaScript `Object`.

Alternatively, use `getJSON()` or send the `application/json` mime type.

Answer (score 0):

The data is the Json so you will want to do this:

```
success: function (data) {
  var newobject = eval(data);
  alert(newobject.msg);

}
```

or do this:

```
$ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (newObject) {
   alert(newobject.msg);
}
});
```

Comment: Do not do this. Eval is very bad! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval

Comment: don't worry had no intention of using eval :) although I do appreciate the attempt to help :)