# Fetching Data Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a php file that fetches the last price and description of item upon selecting an itemcode from a dropdown list.

**The Issue:**

When the request is made on the front end, the request is sent to the processing page, which returns a JSON data.

It works perfectly well on my local windows Server. Upon migration to a Live Windows Server, it throws the error like this:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data var data4=JSON.parse(data4);`

When I inspect the element using firebug on Firefox browser, I discover that the processing script shows `200K OK 581ms`, which indicate the processing script is fine. But below that is this error of :

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data
var data4=JSON.parse(data4);`

When I checked further, the processing script which is OK, on the **Response** and HTML TAB, **displays the expected result**, which is supposed to show on the requesting (front-end) page.

I need help figuring out why this is happening. Kindly find the pages below.

**Front-end page script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/newJquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.partno").change(function(){
       var selectedCustomer = $(".partno option:selected").val();
       $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"process-grpid.php",data:{custid:selectedCustomer}}).done(function(data4){
            var data4=JSON.parse(data4);
           //using php-mysql before
           if(data4.sta == 0){
           $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
           $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);
           }else{
            $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
           $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);   

           }
       });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

**Process-grpid.php script:**

```
<?php
       if(isset($_POST["custid"])){

                include 'includes/session.php';
                include 'includes/db_connection.php';
                include 'includes/functions.php';
                 $partid = $_POST["custid"];
                 if($partid !== 'Select PartNo'){ 
             $gets = "SELECT * FROM tab_stock WHERE itemName='".$partid."'";
             $get = mysqli_query($connection,$gets);

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get);


          $desc = $row['description'];
          $lprice = $row['Rate'];
          if($partid=='N/A'){
              $res["sta"]=0;
              $res["ref"]="<input type='text'   class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' required='required'/>";
              $res["lprice"]="<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur'   required='required'/>";
          }else{
              $res["sta"]=1;
              $res["ref"]="<input type='text'  value='$desc' class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";
              $res["lprice"]="<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur' value='$lprice'  readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";  

          }
          echo json_encode($res);
          }

         }
```

[image]

Comment: `var data4 = JSON.parse(data4)` -> You haven't defined the variable data4 and yet you run a function on it?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy It's shadowing a function parameter.

Comment: First, delete the var. Second, show the code in Fiddle so that we can debug more easily, or directly link us to your site

Comment: (It's better to use `===` for equality comparisons, especially with things like numbers.)

Comment: And why are you using if statement? The two don't seem to have a difference

Comment: Compare the testing AJAX response to the live AJAX response and see if there's differences (e.g. encoding differences could alter characters)

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy:I needed to use use if, because, it will responsed to N/A and when the itemCode is selected.

Comment: @Dave please show us the Response, and not HTML part, as revealed in your developing tool

Comment: @gcampbell: I have tried the ===, yet it is still showing the same parse error, even after specifying the datatype:json. yet the error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data

Comment: Can you try `console.log(data4)`?

Comment: @gcampbell:how can i use console.log(data4)?

Comment: `console.log(data4)` is javascript statement. Type it in the console and see what is in data4

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy It would have to be inside the Ajax callback.

Comment: @gcampbell: From the console, as I have shown above, the processing script  returns the expected values, but only not displaying them in the Requested Page

Comment: @Dave Show the value to us. Maybe you overlooked smth

Comment: {"sta":1,"ref":"Bearing Thrust","lprice":"5000"}

Comment: No, reviewing the PHP code, ref and lprice should be HTML codes

Answer (score 0):

One reason the console is returning 200OK because the requested server is there, but the response it is expecting(JSON) was not valid.

You also did not specify the `dataType:'json'` in your ajax request which tells that you are expecting json data and not just plain text.

Comment: OP has already used `JSON.parse` to convert the text to JSON.

Comment: But indeed, the JSON may be invalid

Comment: Here's some attest to that -- http://www.valtira.com/valtira-blog/valtira-blog-the-importance-of-valid-JSON

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: What do you suggest I do, taking into cognisance that this code works perfectly on windows server and the live server is also windows server

Comment: @There was no Upgrade at all.

Comment: @graceth: I have included this part, yet it is still showing SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are declaring data4 twice, once in the function def `function(data4)` and then again at `var data4=...`. It should work if you use separate variable names. It's a good idea to avoid reusing a variable name in 2 different contexts in the same function.

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
    url:"process-grpid.php",
    data:
    {
        custid:selectedCustomer
    }
}).done(function(response){

       var data4 = JSON.parse(response);

       if(data4.sta == 0){
           $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
           $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);
       }else{
           $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
           $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);   

       }
});
```

One thing to consider is that JS understands JSON natively. Meaning, you don't need to use JSON.parse. You only need to tell it to expect JSON `dataType: 'json',`. I would use `success:` instead of `done()`. `done()` may not work as expected because it doesn't care about success. I would also use a truthy if statement. Also your if and else statements do the same thing. One of those appears to be unneeded. Lastly, add an error callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process-grpid.php",

    dataType: 'json', // expected dataType of the response

    data: {
        custid: selectedCustomer
    },
    success: function(response) {

        var data4 = response;

        if (data4.someValueThatShouldBePresent) {
            $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
            $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);
        } else {
            $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
            $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);

        }
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
            // This callback will trigger on an unsuccessful request
            alert('Unable to connect, try again. ');
        }
});
```

Comment: I have made the changes. yet display :Json.Parse Error.Any futher assistance?

Comment: I edited my answer to be more inline with what I actually do.  I would also check to see that `process-grpid.php` actually returns JSON by changing the $_POST to $_REQUEST and constructing a GET in the address bar of a browser.

Comment: You need to *look directly at the JSON data stream.*  That could be as simple as adding a pop-up message to the code that receives it, before it attempts to decode it. The software is telling you that there's an error in it.  ### Also, I specifically *dis*agree with the notion that you should not be using `JSON.parse`:  although the JSON format is directly based on JavaScript syntax, there is a potential for JavaScript code-injection if you simply "evaluate" what you get.  ("Don't be *that* trusting of anything anywhere ...") It also gives you "reliable detection of errors like these!"

Comment: A possible cause of a message like this ... is that what you're actually getting, in this scenario, actually *isn't JSON!*  Maybe it's an error-message, instead.  **LQQK** at it.

Comment: @DieterDonnert: I tried it it just display the alert message, which is the error side of the code. WHat could be the issue?

Comment: I would suspect a php or mysql error is stopping execution before the json_encode  - That php error message would not be valid JSON. The $_REQUEST thing I suggested would show you the error message. Or do as Mike suggests and view the stream before JSON.parse. `alert(response)` maybe.

Comment: @MikeRobinson, jQuery dataType does not use eval. I would never eval anything - ever. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449220/jquery-uses-new-functionreturn-data-instead-of-evaldata-to-parse

Comment: "A very wise move ..." In any case:  use the browser's debugger features to LOOK AT what you got back. I agree with Dieter, "two replies back," that it's very, very likely that what the server is handing you IS NOT "JSON." (It could well be: "500 Internal Server Error.")  :-/

Comment: Please, I am still in a fixed as regards the question above. Still not working. Or Is there a way of getting data from processed script into the Requesting Page without using Json.Parse(data)?

Comment: Json.Parse is not the problem. The evidence points to the php script. Did you trouble shoot the php script? What were your findings?