# Safe json parsing with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery with json. My client pages generate json, which I store on my server. The clients can then fetch the json back out later, parse, and show it.

Since my clients are generating the json, it may not be safe. I think jquery uses eval() internally. Is that true? Is there a way to use the native json parsers from the browsers where available, otherwise fall back to manual parsing if not? I'm new to jquery so I don't know where I'd insert my own parsing code. I'm doing something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myservlet',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error loading JSON');
    },
    success: function(json){
        alert("It worked!: " + json.name + ", " + json.grade);
    }
});
```

so in the success() method, the json object is already parsed for me. Is there a way to catch it as a raw string first? Then I can decide whether to use the native parsers or manual parsing (hoping there's a jquery plugin for that..).

The articles I'm reading are all from different years, so I don't know if jquery has already abandoned eval() already for json,

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version has [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).  It will use native JSON in browsers that have it.  For older ones, it will do a regex sanity check, then use new Function() (basically eval).

Since you specified 'json' as the dataType, it will use parseJSON here.  This is handled in the internal [httpData function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L648)

Comment: but if the browser does not support it, then does it fall back to using eval()? If so, I'd be exposing my users to risk? Thanks

Comment: It does use `new Function` (basically `eval`) if native JSON isn't available, but only after sanity-checking it with regex from JSON.org (see http://www.json.org/json2.js).  This *should* prevent script injection.

Comment: Ah great. But how do we use jQuery.parseJSON() with the $.ajax({}) example above? By the time the function returns, the response has already been parsed by jQuery, right?

Comment: Latest jQuery will use parseJSON internally. .