# How would I read such a JSON structure?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"some_id":
    [
    {"city":"Bellevue"},
    {"state":"Washington"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: "open curly bracket, quote, some ID, colon, open square bracket, open curly bracket, quote, city, quote, colon, quote, Bell View, close curly bracket, comma, open curly bracket, quote, state, quote, colon, quote, Washington, quote, close curly bracket, close square bracket, close curly bracket." :D

Comment: See [Alternatives to JavaScript eval() for parsing JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945015/alternatives-to-javascript-eval-for-parsing-json) and [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) for a number of methods

Answer (score 5):

```
var theJSonString = '({"some_id": [ {"city":"Bellevue"}, {"state":"Washington"} ] })';
var x = eval(theJSonString);
alert(x.some_id[0].city); // will display "Bellevue"
```

Comment: If you parse JSON with `eval`, you need to wrap the contents in parentheses (e.g. `eval('(' + theString + ')')`), otherwise it gets parsed as a block statement instead of an object literal.

Answer (score 3):

```
var json = {"some_id": [ {"city":"Bellevue"}, {"state":"Washington"} ] }
```

`json.some_id[0].city` equals "Bellevue"

and

`json.some_id[1].state` equals "Washington"

Answer (score 0):

And [this (the json parser and stringifier from json.org)](http://www.json.org/js.html) might help :) (check the link at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

All current browsers support `window.JSON.parse()`. It takes a JSON formatted string and returns a Javascript object or array.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/KnbAJ/

Script:

```js
var json = '{"some_id":[{"city":"Bellevue"},{"state":"Washington"}]}'
    object = window.JSON.parse( json );

document.getElementById( 'length' ).textContent = object.some_id.length;
document.getElementById( 'city' ).textContent = object.some_id[0].city;
document.getElementById( 'state' ).textContent = object.some_id[1].state;
```

HTML:

```html
length: <span id="length"></span><br />
some_id[0].city: <span id="city"></span><br />
some_id[1].state: <span id="state"></span><br />
```

Output:

```
length: 2
some_id[0].city: Bellevue
some_id[1].state: Washington
```