# PHP, JavaScript and MySQL: updating and passing of variables

Tags: javascript, mysql, variables, updates

I am trying to increment a number and update the database and then display the number without refreshing the page. I am just wondering, is there a way to read/update MySQL using JavaScript?

I tried searching around, and it seems you have to call another program that changes the values for you. Right now I have

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");

echo "connected!<br>";

$extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles")or die ("Not working");

//$numrows = mysql_num_row($extract);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $article = $row['article'];
    $thumbsup= $row['thumbs_up'];
    $thumbsdown = $row['thumbs_down'];
    $date = $row['date_time'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET thumbsup = 1");
}
?>
```

So I am wondering, once this page updates the database, how do you get the updated value into the JavaScript function? Right now I am just reading it from a file

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/ajax/folder5/includes/a.txt", true);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a server-side script that fetches data all you need to do is return it as a response to your `XMLHttpRequest` and handle it by using a `callback` function. Assuming you want to return `$id, $article, $thumbsup` ..etc you can put it in an array and encode it, as suggested you can use `json_encode()`. In your PHP script you can do something like:

```
$Response = array(
     'Id' => $id,
     'Article' => $article',
     'ThumbsUp' => $thumbsup
)

echo json_encode($Response);
exit;
```

And in your Javascript you may need to add a response handler, like:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

 if (syndLinkRequest.readyState != 4)
    return;

  var result = xmlHttp.responseText;

  /* if you've returned javascript instead of xml or text, 
    you can eval(result) to access the javascript variables returned.
  */

  // do your thing
  }
```

Of couse you need to change the way you request data instead of using GET to text file, in this case you may want to request directly to the PHP script and return the result:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ajax/update.php", true); // this will return the response
```

Essentially, that's all you need. 
For more brief example you can refer [here](http://swik.net/Ajax/How+to+use+XMLHttpRequest).

Also check jQuery's ajax functions as it may help you a lot.

****EDIT****

Added additional info.
Since we're returning a result which is JSON (by using json_encode), you need to add a header for the content type, add this at the top most part of your script just below the `<?php` part:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And based on the example above assuming we have this as the response:

```
$Response = array( 'Id' => $id,  'Article' => $article,'ThumbsUp' => $thumbsup);
echo json_encode($Response);
exit;
```

Once you receive this in your `callback` function this will be translated to something like (with sample values):

```
{"Id":1,"Article":20,"ThumbsUp":30}
```

which is given to the result variable:

```
var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

To be sure we get the response evaluated we will use `eval()` to the result string so you can get values off of it by accessing properties. Take this for example:

```
var result = eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Once that's done you can access properties from the result variable like `result.ThumbsUp` which gives you `30` based on the example. You can then assign that value wherever you need it to be like: `document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = result.ThumbsUp;` I hope this gives you a clearer idea.

A note to using `eval()`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945015/alternatives-to-javascript-eval-for-parsing-json).

Comment: Uhmmm, i tried what you said, and i dont seem to get any ouput

Comment: hey, I edited my answer to add some new points you may want to try

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with using XMLHttpRequest.  Basically, you just have to make a script that has the output you want (instead of GETing a static text file).

A good choice for your PHP AJAX script's output is JSON.  You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) for this.  There are other possibilities, too, including XML.

Comment: So, how would i exactly pass over the value to the javascript function?