# Converting javascript object to ordered comma separated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, hash

I am trying to get the items in the json arranged in an orderly manner. I was able to select the "term" values present in the json, but is it possible to arrange this in the manner I have shown in the expected output part? I have added a jsfiddle link to show where I have reached:

```js
[
    {
        "Link": "http://testLink.com/1",
        "_index": "test",
        "_source": {
            "Author": "SAM",
            "Map": [
                {
                    "Company": [
                        {
                            "Apple_Inc": [
                                {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "term": "Apple"
                                }
                            ],
                            "sector": "Technology",
                            "term": "Apple Inc",
                            "ticker": "AAPL",
                            "type": "BCap"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "Country": [
                        {
                            "Canada": [
                                {
                                    "Canada": [
                                        {
                                            "count": 1,
                                            "term": "Toronto"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "term": "Canada"
                                }
                            ],
                            "United_States": [
                                {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "term": "United States"
                                }
                            ],
                            "currency": "Dollar (USD)",
                            "index": "DOW JONES INDUS. AVG , S&P 500 INDEX , NASDAQ COMPOSITE INDEX",
                            "region": "North Americas",
                            "term": "Canada"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Country"
                },
                {
                    "Personality": [
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Bart Prince"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Thomas"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Deborah Hornstra"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Henderson Sotheby"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Max Alliance"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 5,
                    "term": "Personality"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "YMFT112"
    },
    {
        "Link": "http://testLink.com/2",
        "_id": "YMFT113",
        "_index": "test",
        "_source": {
            "Author": "MAX",
            "Map": [
                {
                    "Company": [
                        {
                            "Microsoft Corp": [
                                {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "term": "Microsoft"
                                }
                            ],
                            "sector": "Technology",
                            "term": "Microsoft",
                            "ticker": "AAPL",
                            "type": "BCap"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "Country": [
                        {
                            "Brazil": [
                                {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "term": "Brazil"
                                }
                            ],
                            "currency": "Dollar (USD)",
                            "region": "South Americas",
                            "term": "Brazil"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Country"
                },
                {
                    "SalesRelated": [
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "traffic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Personality": [
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Maximor"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "R.V.P"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Wenger"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "SAF"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 4,
                    "term": "Personality"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

http://jsbin.com/exuwet/3/edit

---

Prompt Input
If field Selected = `Country`,

Expected Output:

```
YMFT112;    Country;    United States;  United States;      NA;         http://testLink.com/1;

YMFT112;    Country;    Canada;         Canada;             Toronto;    http://testLink.com/1;

YMFT113;    Country;    Brazil;         Brazil;             NA;         http://testLink.com/2;
```

If field Selected = `Company`,

Expected Output:

```
YMFT112; Company;   Apple Inc;      Apple;      http://testLink.com/1;

YMFT113; Company;   Microsoft Corp; Microsoft;  http://testLink.com/2;
```

Comment: have you tried `eval('(' + json_object + ')')`? creating the object from there on won't be a problem.

Comment: I havent tried eval, actually Ive look in to it, Im dealing with josn string for the first time.

Comment: I have posted my answer. Please follow the instructions, and I'm sure you'll be able to create a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON object when natively available or use [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) as a shim.

After that it's just a matter of using JavaScript's built in sorting capability. You supply a function that compares to array items against each other

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
    var nameA = a._source.Map.Company.term;
    var nameB = b._source.Map.Company.term;

    if (nameA === nameB) {
        return 0;
    } else if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1
    }
    return 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With `eval('(' + json_object + ')')`, you will be able to create a JavaScript Object. This object will be an array, and you can acess the properties using `.`.
For example, if your `json_object` is called data, for example:
Then

```
    var temp = eval('(' + data + ')'); // temp now is an array.
```

if you want to access the first `_index` or `id` from the `json` object:

```
    "_index": "test",
    "id": "YMFT112",
```

do alert(`temp[0]._index`), and it will show you `"test"`. For the other properties, follow the same logic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945015/alternatives-to-javascript-eval-for-parsing-json) stackoverflow question, or the [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) page will help you understand what you have to do in other to have your task accomplished. Yahoo has an API called [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/json/) which may be even more helpful.

Comment: @user1371896 I think this http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/json/ is exactly what you need.

Comment: Ive reached this far in terms of listing out all the entities http://jsbin.com/exuwet/2/edit bt Im searching a way to get it in an order

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{"_index":"test","id":"YMFT112","_source":{"Author":"SAM","Map":[{"count":1,"term":"Company","Company":[{"sector":"Technology","ticker":"AAPL","Apple_Inc":[{"count":1,"term":"Apple"}],"term":"Apple Inc","type":"BCap"}]},{"count":1,"term":"Country","Country":[{"region":"North Americas","index":"DOW JONES INDUS. AVG , S&P 500 INDEX , NASDAQ COMPOSITE INDEX","United_States":[{"count":1,"term":"United States"}],"term":"Canada","currency":"Dollar (USD)","Canada":[{"count":1,"term":"Canada","Canada":[{"count":1,"term":"Toronto"}]}]}]},{"count":5,"term":"Personality","Personality":[{"count":1,"term":"Bart Prince"},{"count":1,"term":"Thomas"},{"count":1,"term":"Deborah Hornstra"},{"count":1,"term":"Henderson Sotheby"},{"count":1,"term":"Max Alliance"}]}]},"Link":"http://testLink.com/1"},{"_index":"test","_id":"YMFT113","_source":{"Author":"MAX","Map":[{"count":1,"term":"Company","Company":[{"sector":"Technology","ticker":"AAPL","Microsoft Corp":[{"count":1,"term":"Microsoft"}],"term":"Microsoft","type":"BCap"}]},{"count":1,"term":"Country","Country":[{"region":"South Americas","Brazil":[{"count":1,"term":"Brazil"}],"term":"Brazil","currency":"Dollar (USD)"}]},{"SalesRelated":[{"count":1,"term":"traffic"}]},{"count":4,"term":"Personality","Personality":[{"count":1,"term":"Maximor"},{"count":1,"term":"R.V.P"},{"count":1,"term":"Wenger"},{"count":1,"term":"SAF"}]}]},"Link":"http://testLink.com/2"}];

const find = (term, input) => {
  const r = objectScan([`[*]._source.Map[*].${term}[*].**.term`], {
    reverse: false,
    filterFn: ({ key, parents, context }) => {
      if (Object.values(parents[0]).some((e) => e instanceof Object)) {
        return;
      }
      const root = parents[parents.length - 2];
      context.push([
        root.id || root._id,
        parents[parents.length - 5].term,
        key[key.length - 3].replace(/_/g, ' '),
        ...parents.slice(0, -7).filter((e) => !Array.isArray(e)).map((p) => p.term).reverse(),
        root.Link
      ]);
    }
  })(input, []);
  const maxLength = Math.max(...r.map((e) => e.length));
  r
    .filter((e) => e.length < maxLength)
    .forEach((e) => e.splice(-1, 0, 'NA'.repeat(maxLength - e.length)));
  return r;
};

console.log(find('Country', data).map((e) => e.join(';    ')).join('\n'));
/* =>
YMFT112;    Country;    United States;  United States;      NA;         http://testLink.com/1
YMFT112;    Country;    Canada;         Canada;             Toronto;    http://testLink.com/1
YMFT113;    Country;    Brazil;         Brazil;             NA;         http://testLink.com/2
 */
console.log(find('Company', data).map((e) => e.join(';    ')).join('\n'));
/* =>
YMFT112; Company;   Apple Inc;      Apple;      http://testLink.com/1
YMFT113; Company;   Microsoft Corp; Microsoft;  http://testLink.com/2
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)