# How to figure out Nginx status code 499

Tags: nginx

**My Setup :**

> Curl --> AWS ELB --> Nginx --> NodeJS

When number of request High then I face this issue.

**Nginx access logs**

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Oct/2014:13:23:40 +0000] "POST /some/calls/object HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "curl/7.27.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Oct/2014:13:23:40 +0000] "POST /some/calls/object HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "curl/7.27.0"
```

**Nginx error logs**

```
2014/10/30 13:23:40 [info] 11181#0: *17811 client xx.xx.xx.xx closed keepalive connection
2014/10/30 13:23:40 [info] 11181#0: *17631 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "POST /some/calls/objects HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/some/calls/object", host: "example.com"
```

**NodeJS logs**

```
2014-10-30T13:23:40.074Z : info :  req.method GET
2014-10-30T13:23:40.074Z : info :  req.url /some/calls/objects
2014-10-30T13:23:40.074Z : info :  error { message: 'Request Timed Out!' }
2014-10-30T13:23:40.075Z : info :  req.method GET
2014-10-30T13:23:40.075Z : info :  req.url /some/calls/objects
2014-10-30T13:23:40.075Z : info :  error { message: 'Request Timed Out!' }
2014-10-30T13:23:40.075Z : info :  error.stack undefined
2014-10-30T13:23:40.076Z : info :  error.stack undefined
```

---

**Question**

as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973304/nginx-an-d-499-error-codes) 499 means client closed the connection, but my question is, who is the client in this scenario, is ELB closing the connection or curl or nodejs ?

I've also observed that nodejs takes 60+ seconds to respond calls, if nodejs encounter Timed out issue, then it keep occurring again and again.

Comment: For nginx client is ELB.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but still found by google when searching for `499` nginx: A `499` also happens when a load balancer (LB) is in place or a proxy and the upstream (i.e., the proxy) times out, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973304/nginx-499-error-codes/27348833. So it could also be the `nodeJS` that timed out.