# No live upstreams while connecting to upstream, but upsteam is OK

Tags: nginx

I have a really weird issue with NGINX.

I have the following `upstream.conf` file, with the following upstream:

```
upstream files_1 {
    least_conn;
    check interval=5000 rise=3 fall=3 timeout=120 type=ssl_hello;

    server mymachine:6006 ;
}
```

In locations.conf:

```
location ~ "^/files(?<command>.+)/[0123]" {
        rewrite ^ $command break;
        proxy_pass https://files_1 ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

In /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost               mymachine
```

When I do: `wget https://mynachine:6006/alive  --no-check-certificate`, I get `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK`. I also verified that port 6006 is listening with netstat, and its OK.

But when I send to the NGINX file server a request, I get the following error:

> no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: .., request: "POST /files/save/2 HTTP/1.1, upstream: "https://files_1/save"

But the upstream is OK. What is the problem?

Comment: Is that the only error message?

Comment: @RichardSmith:  Yes. Before that, in `error.log` I get the following line: `a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000025...`

Comment: Dis you manage to fix this issue? I am having the same problem trying to use Nginx as a proxy server to a java server.

Comment: Actually got a similar problem today. Without even changing anything. And the setup has worked with no problem for a few months. Until today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When defining `upstream` Nginx treats the destination server and something that can be up or down. Nginx decides if your upstream is down or not based on `fail_timeout` (default 10s) and `max_fails` (default 1)

So if you have a few slow requests that timeout, Nginx can decide that the server in your upstream is down, and because you only have one, the whole upstream is effectively down, and Nginx reports `no live upstreams`.  Better explained here:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/

I had a similar problem and you can prevent this overriding those settings.

For example:

```
upstream files_1 {
    least_conn;
    check interval=5000 rise=3 fall=3 timeout=120 type=ssl_hello max_fails=0;
    server mymachine:6006 ;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be `health_check`, not `check`, and is a Nginx Plus (premium) feature according to docs.

Comment: bizarrely, if there's only one upstream it's supposed to never disable it but sometimes treats it as two if it has ipv6 and ipv4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924751/32453 so yeah this is right...somehow the request before this "timed out" or marked the upstream as failed, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550758/32453

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error `no live upstreams while connecting to upstream`

Mine was SSL related: adding `proxy_ssl_server_name on` solved it.

```
location / {
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_pass https://my_upstream;
  }
```

Comment: how did you figure out its SSL related? any specific error?

Comment: I can't remember anything else no

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a docker-compose setup, you have to use the service name in url instead of IP, eg:

```
    server{
           location / {
                proxy_pass http://com_api;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            }
    }
        
   upstream com_api {
      server api:6060; //<----------where api is service name
   }
```