# nginx 502 for 10s while upstream is restarting

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a very simple config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name: example.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

However when I restart my backend (for example Node.JS restarted on change by nodemon), even if the backend starts like in 2 seconds, Nginx returns a 502 for 10s and this shows in the logs:

```
2022/05/10 16:10:48 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2241 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:48 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2241 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:49 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2244 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:50 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2245 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:51 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2246 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:52 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2247 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:53 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2248 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:54 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2249 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:55 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2250 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:57 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2251 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
2022/05/10 16:10:58 [error] 2013398#2013398: *2252 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.fr, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "example.fr"
```

I've seen that for the `upstream` directive there are some controls (`max_fails` and `fail_timeout` (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#max_fails)) but this only seems to apply to `upstream` and I cannot find equivalent options for plain `proxy_pass`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

Quoting user [@rogerdpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924751/2367848) for the long answer:

> The really tricky part is that if you specify proxy_pass to
> "localhost" and your box happens to also have ipv6 and ipv4 "versions
> of localhost" on it at the same time (most boxes do by default), it
> will count as if you had a "list" of multiple servers in your server
> group, which means you can get into the situation above of having it
> return "502 for 10s" even though you list only [one server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550758/32453).
>
> See [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream_tries) "If a domain name resolves to several addresses, all of them
> will be used in a round-robin fashion." One workaround is to declare
> it as `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` (its ipv4 address) to
> [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550758/32453) it being both ipv6 and ipv4.   Then it counts as "only a
> single server" behavior.

*(answering my own question because the answers explaining the problem were [buried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924751/2367848) or [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550758/2367848) wasn't really explicit about the particular symptoms I had)*

Comment: happy that you found my answer, i remember debugging this problem was reaaaally frustrating ;)