# How to resolve 'no live upstreams' error in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have set up a load balancer with nginx. In here I used health check in my configuration file. when I add 'match' parameter to health check and restart the server, I got 'no live upstream' in the error log. But at that time all the other servers are available to get requests.

Why has this kind of error occurred?

My match function in **nginx.conf** file

```
match check_server {
        status 200;
        header Content-Type = text/html;
    }
```

**load_balancer.conf**

```
health_check interval=2 passes=3 fails=2 match=check_server;
```

**error in error.log:**

> 2019/01/17 13:16:26 [error] 9853#9853: *13 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.x.x, server: xxx.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://backends/", host: "xxx.com"

Comment: show us your upstream section

Comment: Thank you for your kindly response.                         upstream backend {
    zone backend 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:9443;
    server 127.0.0.1:9444;
    #ip_hash;
    sticky learn create=$upstream_cookie_jsessionid
        lookup=$cookie_jsessionid
    zone=client_sessions:1m;
}

Comment: But now it works without showing that error. I didn't change anything.

Comment: good for you)))

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113279/no-live-upstreams-while-connecting-to-upstream-but-upsteam-is-ok