# Heroku - Video won't load - H27 Client Request Interrupted

Tags: heroku, webserver, client, httprequest

I have a video that is about 2 minutes long and  6.32MB in size. When I run a local server (using Python), the video loads just fine. However, when I try opening it on my website (hosted on Heroku), the video does not load.

This is the associated Heroku log:

```
sock=client
at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted"
method=GET path="/video.mp4" host=somewhere.com
dyno=web.1
connect=0ms service=26ms
status=499
bytes=
protocol=http
```

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410932/2354735) states,

> HTTP 499 in Nginx means that the client closed the connection before
>   the server answered the request. In my experience is usually caused by
>   client side timeout.

[Heroku's description of the 'H27 - Client Request Interrupted' error is](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h27-client-request-interrupted),

> The client socket was closed either in the middle of the request or
>   before a response could be returned. For example, the client closed
>   their browser session before the request was able to complete.

What does this mean in terms of Heroku? What can I do so that my video loads?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to host the video elsewhere =/

From [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#direct-upload),

> There are two approaches to processing and storing file uploads from a
>   Heroku app to S3: direct and pass-through.
>
> **Direct upload**
>   This is the preferred approach if you’re working with
>   file uploads bigger than 4MB. The idea is to skip the hop to your
>   dyno, making a direct connection from the end user browser to S3.