# Flask with nginx and gunicorn curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am running flask application with nginx and Gunicorn, I am getting below error:

```
[root@master nginx]# curl http://127.0.0.1
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:80; Connection refused
[root@master nginx]# curl http://127.0.0.1:80
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:80; Connection refused
[root@master nginx]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Note: For some reason I should not use docker compose.  Everywhere examples with docker compose only, not sure multi container can be achieved without docker compose.

I can directly access Flask api endpoint

```
[root@master nginx]# curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
Hello, World![root@master nginx]#
```

I am running Flask api docker image like below:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx-frontend
```

I am running nginx like below:

```
 docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx-frontend
```

Both nginx and flask are running in same host and nginx.conf is below and i guess i am doing something wrong here

```
worker_processes  3;

events { }

http {

  keepalive_timeout  360s;

  server {

      listen 80;
      server_name 127.0.0.1;
      charset utf-8;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
  }
}
```

Nginx docker file:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.2

RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

Python Flask Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 5000:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Complete reference code:

[Code Repo](https://github.com/vidyasagarreddyc/flask-with-gunicorn.git)

Comment: Check if `80` port is open publically.

Comment: firewall is disabled

Comment: What does `nginx -t` give?

Comment: First, you will have to correct the command you showed for running flask docker container. Second, the proxy_pass is pointing to 127.0.0.1:5000, which when translating inside nginx container routes to localhost where the flask app isn't  available. Change it to `http://host.docker.internal:5000` to point it to localhost 5000 port where you have already published flask app's port

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172525/4016794) solution.

You will need to modify the ConfigMap.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort