# Nginx limit upload speed

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, nginx-module

I use Nginx as the reverse proxy. 
How to limit the upload speed in Nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share how to limit the upload speed of reverse proxy in Nginx. 
Limiting download speed is easy as a piece of cake, but not for upload.

Here is the configuration to limit upload speed

- find your directory
  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1;
}

# 1)
# Add a stream
# This stream is used to limit upload speed
stream {

    upstream site {
        server your.upload-api.domain1:8080;
        server your.upload-api.domain1:8080;
    }

    server {

        listen    12345;

        # 19 MiB/min = ~332k/s
        proxy_upload_rate 332k;

        proxy_pass site;

        # you can use directly without upstream
        # your.upload-api.domain1:8080;
    }
}

http {

  server {
    
    # 2)
    # Proxy to the stream that limits upload speed
    location = /upload {
        
        # It will proxy the data immediately if off
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        
        # It will pass to the stream
        # Then the stream passes to your.api.domain1:8080/upload?$args
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345/upload?$args;
   
    }

    # You see? limit the download speed is easy, no stream
    location /download {
        keepalive_timeout  28800s;
        proxy_read_timeout 28800s;
        proxy_buffering off;

        # 75MiB/min = ~1300kilobytes/s
        proxy_limit_rate 1300k;

        proxy_pass your.api.domain1:8080;
    }

  }

}
```

If your Nginx doesn't support the `stream`. 
You may need to add a module.

static:

- `$ ./configure --with-stream`
- `$ make && sudo make install`

dynamic

- `$ ./configure --with-stream=dynamic`
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/

***Note:***
If you have a client such as HAProxy, and Nginx as a server. 
You may face `504 timeout` in HAProxy and `499 client is close` in the Nginx while uploading large files with limiting the low upload speed. 
You should increase or add `timeout server: 605s` or over in HAProxy because we want HAProxy not to close the connection while Nginx is busy uploading to your server.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028228/10258377

Some references:

- https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_upload_rate
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_limit_rate

You will find some other ways by adding third-party modules to limit the upload speed, but it's complex and not working fine

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/
- https://github.com/cfsego/limit_upload_rate

Thank me later ;)