# nginx http 499 status code with node js server

Tags: node.js, nginx

is there anyone who knows about the 499 issues? I'm not able to see the 499 status code in the node server. please help me here to find the root cause.

Comment: Do you have any other proxy server or firewall, load balancer kind of setup in front of your NodeJS application ? Like nginx

Comment: Does this article answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973304/possible-reason-for-nginx-499-error-codes

Comment: @VilsadPP Nginx is there.