# STHTTPRequest and php create a custom error code

Tags: php, ios, iphone, sthttprequest

I'm using sthttprequest and php for webserver communication in my apps. This is a sample request:

```
-(void)GetSomething:(NSString*)Username :(NSString*)Password {


__block STHTTPRequest *up = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",PATHSERVER,@"getsomething.php"]];

up.POSTDictionary = @{@"username":Username,@"password":Password};

up.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *body) {


       //my result data




};

up.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-error description and error code- %@", [error localizedDescription]);

};

[up startAsynchronous];

}
```

When a condition occurs i wanna output an error in my php page to display an alert in sthttprequest error's block:

```
up.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"-error description and error code- %@", [error localizedDescription]);

};
```

It is possible to force a custom code error from a php page to achive this behaviour? Something like:

```
<?php  echo $custom_error_code; ?>

up.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {

  if (error.code==1300){
      //this is the code i have set in php
  }

};
```

I don't want an already assigned error like 503,500,ect... because i risk to display the alert to the user when it makes not sense. I want to use the block error and not a simple string in the completionBlock for pratical reasons.

EDIT

I have found this answer here in stackoverflow 
[Can we create custom HTTP Status codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996569/can-we-create-custom-http-status-codes)

So i can create custom error code where the number isn't already assigned , what i have to respect is the class number 4xx or 5xx. Now my problem is to output a custom error code like "475" from a php page. The method

```
header_status(475);
```

dosen't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23190950/3057259 give me the right way to post a custom error code to sthttprequest that recognize it correctly.