# Returning custom status and code on java rest api

Tags: java, rest, http-status-codes, rs

I am looking for a way to have a custom status and error code that is outside the usual http range of error code.  Something like this:

```
return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(8001).entity("Error replacing document").build();
```

I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal status value: 8001

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Allowed status codes in `Response.status()` are `100..599`:

```
public ResponseBuilder status(int s) {
    if (s < 100 || s > 599) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal status value : " + s);
    }
    ...
```

The list of defined status codes in HTTP: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. Every status code has its meaning and use.

I guess this is a duplicate for [Can we create custom HTTP Status codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996569/can-we-create-custom-http-status-codes)

Comment: In tomcat,any error code works.  apache cxf running in karaf container is facing this issue!

Comment: @SathishKumar The point is, codes outside of the `100..599` are not in HTTP spec, many consider them illegal and it's against good practice.