# Laravel PUT responses with Error 419. The token is added into headers. I still get no result

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, token, fetch

I'm trying to put some body (data or file) using Fetch API together with Laravel (5.5/5.6). I get error 419 (Unknown status), while I add the CSRF-token into headers (because I need it). In my example I've minimized the scope to make it easy to find the reason.

The problem occurs at fetching (I do not get any result: so `result.ok` is not ok).

I saw many people get same problem because of tokens. But here in my example I do use tokens and still have problems with fetching. What's wrong with my code?

**Route (routes\web.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});

Route::put('/test/put', function (Request $request) {
    // PUT some stuff
    return response()->json([
        'feedback' => 'test result is ok!'
    ]);
})->name('test.put');
```

---

**Blade (resources\views\test.blade.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="test-form" method="post" action="{{ route('test.put') }}">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="123" title="Test">
    <button type="submit">Put</button>
</form>
<script>
    (function () {

        function getToken() {
            let metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
            for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
                let meta = metas[i];
                if (meta.name === "csrf-token") {
                    return meta.content;
                }
            }
        }

        function buildOptions(form) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            let testVal = form.querySelector('input[name="test"]').value;
            formData.append("test", testVal);
            let token = getToken();
            let headers = new Headers({
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            });
            return {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: formData,
                headers
            };
        }

        function putIt(form) {
            let url = form.getAttribute('action');
            let options = buildOptions(form);
            fetch(url, options)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response
                    }
                    throw new Error("Response is not ok");
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(err => console.error("Something went wrong", err))
        }

        document.getElementById('test-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            putIt(this);
        });

    })();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**FYI**: I'm sure `x-csrf-token` is present in headers (see screenshot below):
[image]

Comment: check the request headers on inspect and see if there is a token being sent

Comment: it is CSRF token error.

Comment: I've checked, of course. It's ok. `x-csrf-token` is present in the Request-headers. The only problem is: the header name is not in caps.

Comment: I'm not even sure it is a problem.

Comment: What happens if you add `'_method': 'put'` to the FormData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you have to do is move your api routes from web.php file to api.php file
because laravel use a different middleware for each file 
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: Yeah, ok. I do the same. I just don't use `JQuery`. My question is about `Fetch-API`. What's the problem with `Fetch API` and Pure `JavaScript` (`ECMA-6`)?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method

Comment: all what you have to do is to put your api code in api.php not in web.php

Comment: web.php is for Routing. What do you mean?

Comment: Ok. It works. Put it as an answer. I'll check it as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: yes web.php is for routing but api.php is for api call and laravel is exculding tokens in api.php so that what you need

Comment: Ok: Agree. But don't you want to post it as an answer to my question, then I can CHECK it as a correct answer, and other people in the future will find it as a correct answer.

Comment: I just edited my answer and now you can check it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Znar (stackoverflow user) I found the solution. The API-part of routing has to be replaced into `api.php`:

**routes\web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

---

**routes\api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::put('/test/put', function (Request $request) {
    // PUT some stuff
    return response()->json([
        'feedback' => 'test result is ok!'
    ]);
})->name('test.put');
```