# How to post data, and insert it to the database with Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a controller file, which handles retrieving and inserting data to database:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Dream;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class DreamsController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request) {
        $dreamEntry = new Dream();
        $dreamEntry->dream = $request->input('dream');
        $dreamEntry->save();
        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'INSERTED');
    }
}
```

I have this class, for the dreams:

```
class Dream extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'dream'
    ];
}
```

A route in my web.php file:

```
Route::post('upload/submit', array('dream'=>'DreamController@submit'));
```

And a really simple form:

```
<form action="/upload/submit" method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Getting data out from the database works fine, and I can see my `submit` function running, because at the and I see the URL at the root (/), but I'm getting `error 419` What is wrong with the previous code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Laravel Api return 419 status code on POST and PUT Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `csrf` field in your `<form>`, and your `<textarea>` doesn't have a `name=` attribute:

```
<form action="/upload/submit" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <textarea name="dream"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Also, I'm not sure if `array('dream'=>'DreamController@submit')` works, could be simply:

```
Route::post('upload/submit', 'DreamController@submit'); 
// 2nd parameter is the Controller/Function you want to use.
```