# laravel 5.6 - vuejs SPA with Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am setting up this web app with `laravel 5.6`. And I have a scenario that I need to create another folder to develop the `vuejs` SPA independently from the `laravel`. So now I have:

`laravel` will serve the api to `get/post` to database:

```
- www.example.com/sample_api/{id}
- www.example.com/sample_api2/
...
```

and with `cors` middleware setup:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $allowedOrigins = ['http://myroute.xyz', 'http://clarkconcepts.net','http://localhost'];
        $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';
        if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
            return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, cache-control,postman-token, token')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I can `get` from the `laravel` api, but not `post`.
I always get this when I `post` thru the `api`:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/posttest' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

which `localhost:8000` is laravel server and `localhost:8080` is `vuejs`.
I suspect this is because I miss out the header when I `post`, but I am not sure how to do that in this case.

**Update1**

Follow @phil's suggestion, I added `localhost:8080` to the `$allowedOrigins` like so:

```
$allowedOrigins = ['http://myroute.xyz', 'http://clarkconcepts.net','http://localhost','http://localhost:8080'];
```

Now it seems like I can get rid of the preflight issue but new error:
[image]

Did some google, and it seems like it is CSRF token issue. I am now confuse, I thought because I cannot use CSRF Token, that is why all the trouble of `Cors` middleware.

Anyway, Is there a way to resolve this? or How can I add the CSRF Token from `laravel` into the `vuejs` SPA site?

Comment: Your list of `$allowedOrigins` does not contain `http://localhost:8080`. I'm surprised the `GET` request works though. Can you post some screenshots from your browser's _Network_ console showing the request and response headers for both working and non-working requests?

Comment: @Phil See Update1.

Comment: This might help ~ [Why Laravel Api return 419 status code on POST and PUT Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method)

Comment: End up, the best way to achieve this is `api.php`. by just transfer the `/sample_api/{id}` from `web.php` to `api.php`, it will just work without needing any token.