# Exception with message `No message` on posting data from a form

Tags: laravel

I got this error when I access to router:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

I tried to find out that but I couldn't fix it.

**Router(web.php)**

```
Route::get('/test', function ()
{
    return view('subdomains.account.pages.test');
});
Route::post('/testForm', 'FormController@store');
```

**View(subdomains.account.pages.test.blade.php)**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => [ 'FormController@store' ], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('test') !!}
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Ares\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

The problem is that code always use the GET method instead of POST. 
How can I fix it?

**EDIT:** I just found cause this issue is because I don't use Laravel using `php artisan serve`, and I only have a ***virtual host*** in the *public server*, how I can solve this without using artisan serve?

**FIX: (EDITED)**

The issue is by forcing the trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Still now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

**FormController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class FormController extends Controller
{
  public function store()
  {
      return "test";
  }
}
```

subdomains/account/pages/**test.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => [ 'FormController@store' ], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('test') !!}
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function ()
{
    return view('subdomains.account.pages.test');
});
Route::post('/testForm', 'FormController@store');
```

**Output**: When you use your route */test* the *test button* will be displayed on the output page

When you click on the *test button*, it will be redirect to */testForm* page and get the output *test*

Comment: @ProGamersRo No idea about virtual host but I start `php artisan serve` and after I check this code and it is successful working

Comment: try without artisan serve, like, open it by going to the public folder, e.g. localhost/laravel-project-name/public

Comment: Thank you for teaching me @ProGamersRo :) I will check also like: `http://localhost/stackoverflow/public/test` and it is successful working, stackoverflow is my project-name

Comment: Hmm, is weird since at me is not working, which is your laravel version?, also when i will get home i will try to remake the project.

Comment: ok cool @ProGamersRo I have Laravel Framework Version **5.7** , checking later, If you find it useful, please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'testform.store', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('test') !!}
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

**Updated answer**

```
Route::post('/testForm', 'FormController@store')->name('testform.store');

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'testform.store', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('test') !!}
    {!! Form::close(); !!}
```

Comment: Your updated answer looks like incorrect. Because, you can't use route name with url parameter.  It must be ``'route' => 'testform.store'``

Comment: Still not working and you have a bug there, you can't redirect to a route with ``url``, you need to use ``route``.

Comment: Still now working, but is weird cause is working with postman.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use code below for `subdomains.account.pages.test`

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => [ '\Ares\Http\Controllers\FormController@store' ], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('test') !!}
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

Comment: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that the url you tried to access is unregistered, can you try to access `/testForm` using [Chrome's ARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) ?

Comment: with postman is not working because i get the error 419, with post man is working only for the routes from api.php

Comment: I see, please try the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method)

Comment: So with postman is working, but from the form is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude `/testForm` from [Laravel's CRSF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf) ?

Comment: Yes, and i excluded and /test. i could add and a GET route but the POST one will never be called.

Comment: so i used artisan serve, and there is working just fine, but i want to work without using serve, because the website it will be added on a Web Server where i can't use that command.

Comment: On what OS are you developing ? (E.g. Windows, Mac). If possible, please explain your xampp folder structure and your development url scheme

Comment: Windows and for laravel i added a new virtual host for the public folder from laravel project.

Comment: A way to do fix this is by using jQuery to post data and to make an API

Comment: Well, this is getting really weird mate. What laravel version are you using ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to change `Route::post('/testForm', 'FormController@store');` into `Route::post('/test-form', 'FormController@store');`. Please try without using artisan serve.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should remove closer from your routes,

   ```
   Route::get('/test', 'FromController@index');
   Route::post('/testForm', 'FormController@store');
   ```
2. then run,

   ```
   php artisan route:clear
   ```
3. Then submit your form

Comment: The problematic route is `/testForm`, replacing the closure on `/test` should not affect the current problem

Comment: @Bondan Sebastian, His code doesn't have a problem. It's simply because he can't perform "php artisan route:clear". cannot use route caching at all if you have closures in your routes. Selective caching would defeat the object. You should have look at this thread. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319

Comment: No my friend, OP's problem is getting `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` error everytime he tried to access `/testForm` endpoint.

Comment: Then you don't saw all his comment what happend after execute "php artisan cache:clear" he commented see this image https://prnt.sc/m02oc3 he posted.

Comment: I've seen it mate, and from what i see, the cache clearing is successful, it's just Laravel cannot cache `/test` endpoint. If we actually able to cache the `/test` endpoint, still `testForm` always emits an error.

Comment: You don't read the thread mate,

when the app has some closure route,it means cant route cache?
has solution ?

change the app code to not use closure route,or do some others like skip cache for closure route but cache for normals?

Basically, you cannot use route caching at all if you have closures in your routes. Selective caching would defeat the object
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319#issuecomment-73362932

Comment: I see, i do missed that point mate, thanks for pointing out. But still, how does it resolve OP's current problem ? If the route caching is disabled, then any code changes will immediately be applied and there's no need for `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: My point of view. I found no problem in his code. So, It can be his caching problem and Even before me another one suggested similar solution. Let him decide. and his route cache is not disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185826/discussion-between-md-sukel-ali-and-bondan-sebastian).