# Ajax works periodically. Sometimes POST request return error 419

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

With the help of Laravel I create a multilingual website. When I switch languages using Ajax, sometimes I get an error.
**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#LanguageSwitcher").change(function(){
        var locale = $(this).val();
        var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        $.ajax({
            url: "/language",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {locale: locale, _token: _token},
            datatype: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('before send - ' + locale);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::post('/language/', array(
    'before' => 'csrf', 
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@changeLanguage' 
));
```

**Controller:**

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage(Request $request){
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $request->session()->put('locale', $request->locale);
        }
    }
}
```

**layout.blade.php:**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <select id="LanguageSwitcher" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                <option>...code...</option>
                <option>...code...</option>
                <option>...code...</option>
        </select>
```

When I go through another browser everything works. It also works if I go through the incognito mode. Can this be due to the fact that I log in to the admin panel?

Comment: *HTTP Status 419 Used by the Laravel Framework when a CSRF Token is missing or expired* - self explanatory

Comment: Check developer tools network tab and when you are getting the 419 check if the _token parameter is there.

Comment: Taha Paksu - In Chrome: ->dev tools -> Application -> Cookies -> mysite.com there is XSRF-TOKEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, but still did not understand how it works, explain who understands this.
**App\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        // code for updating token when session is expired
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {            
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['session' => 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Try Again']);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ajax call like this.

```php
req = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/search",
    data: {
        "locale": locale,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

    }
});
```

Comment: @futur1st, the particular script jithesh provide is meant to be put on blade template file not js file so as `{{ csrf_token() }}` can have the proper token for CSRF. your code do looks ok as it try to load the CSRF, but you have to ascertain that it was sent in the request. alternative to this, you can simply turn off VerifyCsrfToken middleware on the your url path, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266593/4648586) for better understanding. or you can just [register the route on `api.php` instead](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/401-status).

Answer (score 0):

As I saw your code.
You passing csrf token in your request. the problem you face is, your csrf token is not being updated.

Let's say, you're not reloading your page, on first time your enter to your page, laravel give you csrf token which you providing to ajax through `meta`.

But after some time on the backend(laravel side). your csrf token is updated, but you don't have updated one in client-side.For get the updating one you need to reload the page.

so for this issue, you need to check whenever you get error status 419, request laravel for new csrf token(by making a new route get the csrf token from laravel helper `csrf_token()` return back to ajax) and update to your file. and send back that token to laravel  with you request.

For updating newly token to your page

`document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').setAttribute('content', res.data.csrf);`

or you can refresh your token by reloading the page

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but did not work, after page reloading.

Comment: after page reload you need to get the newly generated token from meta and pass that to ajax nd send request

Comment: what is res - "res.data.csrf"?

Comment: its just getting response from controller with csrf token.
`return response()->json(['status'=>200,'csrf'=>csrf_token()])` 
and on client side , `response.data.csrf`

Comment: After reloading page, i get the new token in ajax: var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
What is the difference how to get a new token?

Comment: you should read..if you dont want to refresh your page then get token by another ajax request with `get`, and if you reloading the page. then problem solve , you dont need to get token via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

add csrf token in meta tag in your blade view

```
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

in your ajax function :

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

            },error:function(err){

            }
    });
```

Comment: I added <meta in layout.blade.php earlier, look at the code from the question.