# Axios 419 (unknown status) Laravel API csrf token gets changed

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, debugging, axios

I'm getting the error when I'm requesting my Laravel backend with `Axios` and getting the data back and requesting another API for some data and that goes well but after the API returns the data and I request my laravel backend to store the data. It returns a response with

> app.js:360 POST http://technotrace.tech/session-adding-api 419 (unknown status)

I've tried checking on my PHP backend and this only stops if I'm disabling the `VerifyCSRFToken` middleware group.

But I need to check the CSRF token anyway for security reasons.

I'm able to understand why the csrf token gets changed on sending request.

If I'm doing just sending the request to my laravel backend then everything goes right but when I'm requesting another api then the problem arrives on sending the request to my backend.

```
function addSession(url, formdata) {

    //Add Session
    axios.post(url, formdata)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)

            var data = res.data;

            if ((data.session_info != null && data.session_info != {})) {
                console.log(data.session_info);
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {

            console.error(err);
        })

}

function getApiDetails() {

    //Start getting api details
    axios.get('https://ipapi.co/json/').then(res => {

            console.log(res)
            var csrf = jr('meta[name="csrf-token"]').get(0).content;
            var ses_id = jr('meta[name="verify-token"]').get(0).content;
            var cur_url = jr('link[rel="canonical"]').get(0).href;

            // console.log(csrf, ses_id, cur_url);

            var url = '/session-adding-api';

            var formdata = new FormData();

            formdata.append('_token', csrf);
            formdata.append('session_token', ses_id);
            formdata.append('session_repeat', 0);
            formdata.append('current_url', cur_url);

            Object.entries(res.data).forEach(entry => {
                // console.log(entry[0], entry[1]);
                formdata.append(entry[0], entry[1]);

            });

            addSession(url, formdata);

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })

    //End getting api details

}

function matchSession() {

    //Match Session Start
    var csrf = jr('meta[name="csrf-token"]').get(0).content;
    var ses_id = jr('input[name="verify-token"]').get(0).content;

    var url = '/session-matching-api';

    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('_token', csrf);
    formdata.append('session_token', ses_id);

    axios.post(url, formdata)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)

            var data = res.data;

            if ((data.match != true)) {

                getApiDetails()

            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    //Match Session

}

matchSession();
```

Comment: I recommend looking into this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method

Comment: Laraval returns a 419 to mean "Page Expired" if the CSRF token is expired or invalid. Check to be sure your CSRF value is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Laravel Api return 419 status code on POST and PUT Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk look what I'm doing to solve this: I disabled CSRF protection first, then I tried sending the csrf token from frontend to backend and pulling the token in the backend via session()->pull('_token') and matching them and it turns out that they are not equal... Why?? and How??

Comment: none of the above answers my problem..