# Laravel Http Client receive 419 response with PUT method 200 with GET

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

I'm using a livewire controller called CallControllerButton.php who is in charge to call a Laravel Controller, the problem is that CallControllerButton should call it with PUT method and everytime the statuscode response is 419 with get it's ok but it's not good.

CallController here is calling syncFromLdap method in UserController like this :

```
public function callUrl($ajaxUrl)
    {
        try {
            /*$client = new Client([
               'base_uri' => URL::to('/'),
                'headers' => ['X-CSRF-Token'=> csrf_token()],
                'timeout' => 5.0,
                'verify'  => false
            ]);
            $request = $client->put($ajaxUrl);*/

            $request = Http::withOptions([
                'headers' => ['X-CSRF-Token'=> csrf_token()],
                'timeout' => 5.0,
                'verify'  => false
            ])->put(URL::to('/').'/'.$ajaxUrl)
            ;

            // PUT successful response is 200 error is 304
            if($request->getStatusCode() == 200){
                session()->flash('message', 'User sync ok');
            }else{
                session()->flash('error', $request->getStatusCode().'/'.$request->getBody());
            }

        }catch (HttpClientException $httpClientException){
            session()->flash('error', 'GuzzleException message : '.$httpClientException->getMessage().' - error code:'.$httpClientException->getCode());
        }

    }
```

and syncFromLdap method is :

```
public function syncFromLdap(User $user)
    {

        Artisan::call('ldap:import', [
            'provider' => 'ldap',
            'user' => $user->name,
            '--no-interaction',
            '--filter' => '(mail='.$user->email.')',
            //'--attributes' => 'cn,mail,samaccountname',
        ]);
        $output = Artisan::output();

        if (str_contains($output,'Successfully imported / synchronized [1]')){
            
            return new Response(null,200);
        }

        return new Response(null,304);

    }
```

off course web.php corresponding route is ok and csrf token is included in headers
What do I've missed ? Thanks

Comment: If this is a request to the same server you need to also send all cookies in addition to the csrf token otherwise the token will not match as there will be no session cookie to match the token against a session. GET is ok because it does not do any CSRF verification

Comment: ok so how to deal with  ?

Comment: is it because of csrf middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-does-the-laravel-api-return-a-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-methods

Comment: Since this is (I'm assuming) called via an artisan command, you can't solve this since the command line does not know of HTTP cookies. You need to make an effort in rewriting the logic so you can call it directly from the controller instead of via artisan

Comment: The artisan command return an output which contain successfully it's just what I need, artisan command is not the culprit the GET method works but it's dirty for a request which should update a user record. I tried to exclude the url from VerifyCsrfToken class but it does not work

Comment: Just don't use an HTTP client to contact your own application. You own the code, just call it directly

Comment: Via Route::put(...) ?

Comment: You're right it works perfect just calling the controller and the method, I'm so dumb !

Answer (score 0):

OK it's working now by excluding the url like that :

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'userSync/*'
    ];
}
```