# Get server response with AJAX error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

for an incorrect Ajax action, I set with HTTP header code to 403 and send the following response :

```
{"code":"403","status":"Forbidden","message":"You cannot do this"}
```

However, I can't access this data when handling my error... Is it possible to acess "message"data from jqXHR ?

something like jqXHR.message ?

Many thanks for your help...

EDIt :

```
error: function (xhr) {
            $(".alert").html(xhr.responseText);
          },
```

This returns :

```
{"code":"403","status":"Forbidden","message":"You cannot do this"}
```

But xhr.responseText.message doesn't return anything ...

EDIT : this code works :

```
  error: function (xhr) {
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    $(".alert").html(jsonResponse.message);
  },
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1637019/139010 though note the comments about using `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Should be jsonResponse["message"], no?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should be getting in jQuery 'error' callback...
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
 }
```

(btw.. ur code?)

Comment: I get "undefined" as alert message

Comment: How did you solved your undefined problem?