# Get the failed request details in general error handling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using `ajaxSetup` to handle all errors generally:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: handleErrors
});

var handleErrors = function(xhr) {
    console.log('this is ');
    console.log(this);
};
```

In this case, `this` is the global scope.

However, if I have an indiviudal error handler for each call:

```
$.ajax({
    error: function(xhr){
        console.log('this is ');
        console.log(this);
    },  
    ...
```

The `this` is the ajax request that was sent, with url, type, contentType etc. How would I get access to that information in my general `handleErrors` function? So if it fails, I know specifically the request that has failed?

Comment: have you checked dis "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405033/get-server-response-with-ajax-error"

Comment: I know how to get the error, i want to get the original request from a general error handling function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery documentation advises to use [`ajaxError`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) for this.

You can attach a function handler to it with the following options:

> handler
>
> `Type: Function( Event event, jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject ajaxSettings, String thrownError )`

`jqXHR` will be your XHR object. While the `thrownError` will be the error message.

> As of jQuery 1.8 it's mandatory to attach this function to the document only.

Comment: thanks, ajaxSettings contains details of the request, which is what i want

Answer (score 1):

> function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ }