# Ajax does not send data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Good morning everyone,

I am a kind of newbie concerning Ajax.
I have already a php script which works.
I know that my php needs to evolve with PDOs but it is another problem.
But i want to implement ajax to avoid the reloading and because i want to learn it.

Php script:

```
<?php 

session_start();

require "connect.php";

$firstName  = $_POST['regFirstName']; 
$lastName  = $_POST['regLastName']; 
$companyName = $_POST['regCompanyName']; 
$email = $_POST['regEmail'];
$password = $_POST['regPassword'];
$confirmPwd = $_POST['regConfirmPwd'];    

$add = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName, companyName, email, password) VALUES ('$firstName' , '$lastName', '$companyName', '$email', '$password') ") or die("Can't  Insert! ");
mail($email, "Your registration has been successful, please note your registration details\n\n ID: $email\n\n Password: $password\n\n" ); 
$success = "Successful! <a href='../login.php'> Click Here </a> to log In.";
echo($success);
```

And below the ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#regForm").submit(registration);

            function registration(){

                var regData = $("#regForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "regScript.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: regData,
                    success: function(){
                        console.log("ok");
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        console.log("regData");
                    }
                });      
    });
```

And the form:

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="regFirstName" name="regFirstName">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="regLastName" name="regLastName">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="regCompanyName" name="regCompanyName">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="email" id="regEmail" name="regEmail">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="password" id="regPassword" name="regPassword">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="password" id="regConfirmPwd" name="regConfirmPwd">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="errorWindowRegister">
    </div>

    <br>

    <button type="reset" name="reset" id="rstRegister" href="#">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="regButton">Register</button>
</form>
```

I don't know how to retrieve the data from Ajax to Php.
The Jquery code seems to work but the data is not well sent to Php.

How to retrieve the data with Ajax and send it to Php?

Regards,
E

Comment: what is the error message. Please post the error message.

Comment: Submiting a FORM redirect user, you need to prevent this behaviour. Search for it and you will find thousand of available examples

Comment: What do you get when you do console.log(regData)?

Comment: it displayed this :[object DeadObject]

Comment: can you expand the object in your console by clicking on the arrow on the left and see what you got?

Comment: [Object { name="regFirstName", value=""}, Object { name="regLastName", value=""}, Object { name="regCompanyName", value=""}, Object { name="regEmail", value=""}, Object { name="regPassword", value=""}, Object { name="regConfirmPwd", value=""}] Although it is the same if i insert values.

Comment: So, it's not ajax that's not sending the data. Try .serialize() instead of .serializeArray() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: A test: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2shvm/ i tried works fine though.

Comment: Now the error is "regFirstName=&regLastName=&regCompanyName=&regEmail=&regPassword=&regConfirmPwd="

Comment: I'm agree with the use of serialize. Anyway, can you edit and show your last code with the place where you put console.log() please.

Comment: I updated the code, still an error =(

Comment: I've read again and I don't see where you print : "regFirstName=&regLastName=...". And you say that it's fill when submit the form so it's normal. The "ok" is not print in the console ?

Comment: Yes, only error is displayed with a console.log of my data

Comment: I am sorry Debflav, actually no error is displayed anymore in my console. But it seems that Ajax does not send data to php. I checked the paths in my php script and all is ok. I think it is due to Ajax because if i don't use it, the php script works (in using the form action)

Comment: You haven't updated your current code... In any case, I've updated my answer. My last answer because I've no more idea. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a semicolon in your script. Anyway you don't stop the event when sending the form. I think you would have another problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#regForm").submit(registration);
    function registration(){
        var regData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
           //...
        })//; Semi-colon is missing here
    }) // Edit: And here extra ')' ?
});
```

Add your console output if you have any errors, please.

---

### Edit

If the Ajax request is the problem, the following should solve your problem. I can't see the modification you already made. But I'm sur at 99% that sample will be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#regForm").submit( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // Avoid page reload
        var regData = $("#regForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "regScript.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: regData,
            dataType: "html", // You want retrieve html (I guess it's the default but it's better to be explicit)
            success: function(myReturnedHtml){
               console.log(myReturnedHtml); // Put the result where you want
            }
            //... 
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks man but I corrected it and i have still not data sent.

Comment: As I said we need your output error (see in developer tool) and I guess you need to stop form submission with [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: The console error which is displayed is [object DeadObject]

Answer (score 0):

What's that `url` is `regScript` in `$.ajax` call. It has to be `regScript.php` right.?

Comment: are you sure the path is correct..? means both files are in same folder.

Comment: also try this link for printing your `$.ajax` error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text

Comment: Yes both file are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this in the Ajax block

```
url: "regScript.php",
type: "POST",
data: "regData="+regData
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#regButton").click(function()
    {
             var regData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "regScript.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: regData,
                success: function(){
                    console.log("OK");
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("NOT OK");
                }
            })  ;    
    });
   });
```

HTML

```
 <input type="button" name="submit" id="regButton" value="Register">
```