# Ajax Image Preloader doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was making a preloader using Ajax but It seems not to work. I want to load an image that if It's there the success does something -alert something-, but if It's not there just the error does another thing -alert another text-, but in this code It doesn´t matter if the image is found or not, both alerts happen no matter what, I mean if the image is found both alerts happen, but if I delete the photo both alerts happen as well, what could be the way to achieve this guys with ajax's complete and error? Thanks for any guideline in this one.

```
function preloadImages()
{   
 var $image = 'http://www.mysite/images/example.jpg';
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: $image,
            complete: function(){
         fileLoaded();
     },
    error: function(){
        errorLoading();
    }
 });    
}

function fileLoaded(){
alert('There is the image');
}

function errorLoading(){
alert('No image');
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to figure out the error out of it as in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text)

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

If the image is in the site directory do it the following way

```
    var image = '../Images/Slider/1.jpg'; // give in the src of the image
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: image,
        success: function (bytes) {
            alert('in');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error!!!')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, If I leave the two double quotation marks FireBugs says that there is a syntax error, but if I change the first marks for single quotation marks the alert happen but there is like a blank alert, I mean no text or anything in the alert box.

Comment: Btw console.log(err.Message) says: Undefined.

Comment: I m trying it out myself too .. are you trying any cross-domain ajax?

Comment: try giving in the image's src

Comment: Man the problem was that I was looking for an image from another site with the whole http://, but using a relative path with ../images/ -as you suggested- It did the trick. Thanks a lot AJ. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Change `complete` to `success`

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: $image,
     success: function(){
     fileLoaded();
 },
error: function(){
    errorLoading();
}
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bj6M/)

Comment: Hi shijin, If I use ´success´ a funny thing is now happening, the ´No Image´ alert happens when actually the photo is there or if it's no there.