# Why ajax code to connect with php is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote the ajax in the JavaScript function. That code is

```
function getValidate(checkID)
{
    alert(checkID);
    $.ajax({                  
        type: 'post',
        url: 'checkval.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {checkID : checkID},
        success: function (response) {

          if (response === "OK"){
            alert("Validation Successed.");

        }else if(response === "NG"){
            alert("Check Already Exists.");
        }
    },
        error : function(err, req) {
        alert("Error Occurred");
    }
  });
 }
```

this code is outputs only "Error Occurred".

the connected php script is

```
<?php
        echo("welcome");
    $check          = $_POST['checkID'];
    $host       = 'localhost';
        $database   = 'database';
        $username   = 'root';
        $password   = 'root';

    $dbc = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

        $checkno = $check;
        $sql = "select claimno from check_details where checkno = $checkno";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows != 0)
        {
                        echo "NG";
        }
                else
                {
                        echo "OK";
                }   
?>
```

at a time of calling the JavaScript function php file not executed......

please give me the idea to success it...........

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: i got "Error Occurred" this as a output...

Comment: Could you include the error message into your question?

Comment: use json_encode() in your php and return it

Comment: where...... into a start of the php file...???

Comment: Check your " url: 'checkval.php'" file name or file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you set datatype to *json* so response data must be `json type`

```
$.ajax({ dataType:"json"});
```

In php, store result in one variable and return json_encode

```
<?php
    echo("welcome");
$check          = $_POST['checkID'];
$host       = 'localhost';
    $database   = 'database';
    $username   = 'root';
    $password   = 'root';

$dbc = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

    $checkno = $check;
    $sql = "select claimno from check_details where checkno = '$checkno'";  //use single quote 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows != 0)
    {
                    $res = "NG";
    }
    else
    {
                    $res = "OK";
    }   
echo json_encode($res);  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
if($rows != 0)
{
    $return =  "NG";
}
else
{
    $return = "OK";
}   


echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Please check path of checkval.php

Comment: both are in a same directory

Comment: error: function(ts) {
           alert(ts.responseText);
           }   Try this

Comment: is to handle ajax error. Please try this and let me know

Comment: it shows this error...."Sorry. you are not allowed access to this resource"... may be i found the exact error..... that's a user privilege error.........

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error occurred, because of below code. Try logging something meaningful to triag this.

```
error : function(err, req) {
        alert("Error Occurred");
    }
```

Please try below code to get a clue of the error

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Reference: [Take a look at this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `php` script is not working well.

Debug it with `try and catch` and see what output is comming.

Comment: php script is working without any error or warnings. the complete problem is ajax...... it's not connected with php script......

Comment: Can you access the php script through a web browser?