# how to display the json data from browser response header

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, web-services

Actually i should display the JSON data in a browser, so far i am getting the data in browser response body but here is the problem. i am facing that not able to display it in browser here picture for better understanding, any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Demo</title> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>

<body>
  <input id="testbutton" type="button" value="Test" />
  <p id="results">results appended here: </p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/SMWS/Rest/parentService/parent/getSchoolDetails',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").append('all good');
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
             error: function() {
                $("#results").append("error");
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: here is the image to understand]

Comment: are you getting alert

Comment: no i am not getting the alert

Comment: did you tried `console.log(data[0]);` in success

Comment: You're requesting jsonp and receiving json. Also that's the response body not the response header.

Comment: it is not even entering into success function always it is entering into failure function

Comment: As Jaronmanda said  try keeping `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: if i put its as json iam getting an error as some "Allow access control origin" ,if i placed jsonp i am getting the json data in response u can see it in the image above

Comment: The first parameter to error function would be something to log

Comment: sorry i didn't get you jaromanda

Comment: Jaromanda says that you should use `error: function(response) { console.log(response); }`

Comment: this what i got in log Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }

Answer (score 1):

1. There are plenty of questions about **ajax requests** that have **response status 200** but raise errors. Take a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success) for example. In this thread it is suggested that error might be caused by the malformed **json** the server is sending to you. You can check out [Corvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111158/532675) and [jaketrent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359620/532675).
2. In order to find out the error response message you may look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text). Define this as your error handler and look for the **responseText** property of xhr parameter:

   ```
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
   ```

Comment: when i replace with that in console showing it as "undefined"

Comment: checkout if the server really supports the **jsonp** requests: is there `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080"` in your response header?