# Reading the error value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am handling the error in a if block in the method where I receive the response from the server. I put the server down in order to test the service unavailable scenario

```
_onResponse: function (err, res) {
   if (err){
 }
```

on doing `alert("error " + err);`
I receive

```
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
    at Request.crossDomainError (http://localhost:9000/index.js:33875:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:9000/index.js:33945:20)
```

I want to read the value of `Error:`

I tried doing `err.message` but then I receive the entire body of the error. 
I tried with `err.name` I just get the text `'Error'`

How do I get the content `Request has been terminated` in a javascript variable?

Comment: May this link will help you:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text

Answer (score 0):

From the response all I can say is this is not the error your server is sending. It is raised by the engine while doing XHR to a domain for which CORS is disabled. To catch this error, wrap the XHR code in `index.js around line 33945` in a `try{} catch(e){}` block. Inside catch block you get hold of the error using the `e` variable.

Your block will handle error only when you get a response from the target server.

Comment: No the the flow is moving inside the error if block even if there is no response from the server.