# how to show Statuscode and message set using response.SendError(status , msg) using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, response

I want show error message which I have set by

```
response.sendError(404 , "Some error message" );
```

to user using jquery.

I tried

Java:  I have set status code and message in java

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR , message);
```

Jquery:

```
$.fileDownload($(this).prop('action'),{
    httpMethod: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function () { 
    // success
}).fail(function (e, url) {
    alert(e +""+url+"!");
});
```

But I am just getting undefiend in alert , How I can get error message sent form the server in jquery in fail block

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text

Comment: @Jens I have  already tried this didn't worked for me...

Comment: You're using fileDownload plugin, aren't you? But: what appens if in .fail() function you console.log all arguments? What the console show you?

Comment: @Nineoclick , Yes I am using filedownload plugin and in console it is printing garbage html and URL for download