# Failed to load resources in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to access some string from *django models* using **ajax**. I'm new to ajax and i don't know where I'm going wrong.

Here is **Jquery** code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.ssd").click(function () {

        var lsid = $(this).attr("id");
        lsid = Number(lsid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/a_solution/",
            data: {
                l_sid: lsid,
            },
            success: console.log("success")
            datatype: 'html',
            error : console.log("oops! something went wrong"),

        });
    });
});
```

Here is **url** mapping in `urls.py` :

```
 url(r'^a_solution/$', views.a_detail, name = 'a_detail'),
```

**PS** :- jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/a_solution/ 403 (Forbidden)
        jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/a_solution/"

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all **POST** requests are protected against CSRF (cross-site request forgery). So you must send the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` along with your Ajax request data.

Usually what I do is render the csrf token somewhere in the template (if you have a form put it inside a form, but since it's an Ajax request, the place doesn't really matter).

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Then in your jQuery code you can access it. Also, in the Ajax call, `success` and `error` expects a function (using the `console.log()` call may cause an error, not sure):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.ssd").click(function () {

        var lsid = $(this).attr("id");
        lsid = Number(lsid);
        var csrf = $("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/a_solution/",
            data: {
                'l_sid': lsid,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            datatype: 'html',
            error: function () {
                console.log("oops! something went wrong");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: After modifying the code it gave `500 (Internal server error)`. can you explain how to get detail error ?

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text)

Don't forget to accept Vitor's answer.