# String to Object

Tags: javascript

So basically I have this code:

```
var string = '{name: "bob", height: 4, weight: 145}';
```

I would like to know if it is possible to convert that string into an object.
so that I can use

```
string.name, string.height, and string.weight
```

(I am retrieving the string variable from a database so I cannot just remove the quotes and make it an object in the first place)

Comment: Why not send the string as JSON and use `JSON.parse( string )`

Comment: Why would you store data like that in a database?

Comment: I have an array of these objects basically and that is how it is being stored.

Comment: I don't think it's worth your time finding a solution for this problem, because the problem is actually your string format, using JSON is IMO the proper solution here, instead of trying to parse a format that you created which btw looks very similar to JSON -> `var string = '{"name": "bob", "height": 4, "weight": 145}'`

Comment: ok, thankyou, I am still learning and I am not very familiar with JSON, however, I get what you are saying and will switch to that as it seems the easiest. thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your string is malformed. In order to work with `JSON.parse` or even `jQuery.parseJSON` methods, your keys must have speech marks (`"` ) around them, like so:

```
var str = '{"name": "bob", "height": 4, "weight": 145}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

You can test this by adding `console.log(obj);​` as the final line. Here is my [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/9YCTL/).

So try to see if you can pull down the data from the server in the format I have suggested and it can then easily be parsed into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 3):

eval, as suggested by Igor, will certainly work but is vulnerable to attack.

Instead you could use a library to parse it for you. There are options in the following link:

[Eval is evil... So what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646597/eval-is-evil-so-what-should-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `string` for a variable name, but:

```
var obj = eval(string);
alert(obj.name);
```

or you can use `jQuery.parseJSON`: api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON.

Comment: thankyou string is just an example I was using. isnt eval bad though?

Comment: Actually it would be something like `eval('var obj = '+string);`

Comment: that works but, will it open up my application to any vulnerabilities?

Comment: I've decided to switch the variable to JSON and use jQuery.parseJSON, thankyou