# How to Change it to an array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery's `$.post` to get data from php[from mysql] file data, what we get looks like that:

```
data = [['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]
```

when I assign this to variable it stores as string as this:

```
v1 = "[['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]"; [v1 = data]
```

but I require it to like this:

```
v2 = [['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]];
```

not as a string.

To be more clarifying, you can understand by alert v1 & v2

when you alert `v2` you get `12-25-2012,62,12-26-2012,60`
when you alert `v1` you get `[['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]`

there's difference, and I want `v1` to look like `v2`.

Comment: You could use `eval`. Or output a better format if you can edit the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, though not sure whethe it would work:

```
v1=eval(data);
```

Please note that [eval() is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646597/eval-is-evil-so-what-should-i-use-instead). Also I would **strongly** suggest, that you alter the php code to send it in some other format and then you could append these to a javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify what type of data you expect to get in the jQuery `$.post` function according to the docs for [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Let php echo exactly this

```
$data = "[['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]";
exit(0);
```

and

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
 function(data) {
   process(data);
 }, 
 "JSON" //this will tell your calling post that the return data is to be considered JSON
);
```

Comment: @AzWadehra did it work?  If yes then try selecting one of the answers :)

Comment: no above comment is my code is look like this, its not the solution of my question/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and set JSON asthe the expected response type or parse the string

```
JSON.parse(v1);
```

As @m90 pointed out, single quotes aren't valid in JSON. I've missed that. You will have to change the php file to respond a proper JSON or replace the single quotes with double quotes before parsing the string.

Comment: `JSON.parse` won't accept the Strings in single quotes I think

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is only capable of transferring Strings, so you have to handle the conversion (to a String in PHP and back to the actual data in JS) yourself (this means that you cannot pass data like in your example: `data = [['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]`). The most common format used in AJAX calls is JSON. Yet, JSON is using double quotes only, so the data you are trying to pass in considered invalid.

I would advise you to use proper JSON formatting for your data (using double quotes) so that you can use `JSON.parse` for the job, but in case you are stuck with the formatting of your data you will have to get your hands dirty and use something like a function constructor (or, even worse use `eval`):

```
var v1 = "[['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]"
var a = new Function("return " + v1); //constructs a new function from the given string, in this case returning the passed array
var data = a();

console.log(data);
```

Read about **[using JSON in JavaScript at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)** and **[why you shouldn't be using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646597/eval-is-evil-so-what-should-i-use-instead)** and the likes.

PHP also has a very handy [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method that you can pass an Array and it will automatically be converted into valid JSON.

If you need just a simple String consisting of comma delimited pairs why don't you generate this in PHP and pass it to the JavaScript like this?

Comment: i tried to convert above to jason parse format but won't work
i require that it get data from php that [['12-25-2012',62],['12-26-2012',60]]
and it will show like this - 12-25-2012,62,12-26-2012,60
//

Comment: I think you need to specify on the desired output. Do you want a comma separated string and get rid of the Arrays? Do you want numbers to stay numbers, etc.?

Comment: k actually i generating graph using jqplot plugin and get data from database 
it require data in that format as shown in v2 variable but i get format as v1 i  want to change v1 format as v2 

u can go here to check out one example of jqplot format
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

Comment: That would be pretty basic (and pretty unrelated to your actual question): http://jsfiddle.net/FPLcF/

Comment: that won't work you can try yourself go here
http://jsfiddle.net/45nDy/2/

you can change line1 to output 
then no graph generate when u use line1 it form graph

Answer (score 0):

use this ..

```
    var x= eval(v1);
     alert(x);
```